# Update member collection given input collection using STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `class` with a member `list` of Object (each object has an ID that can be used for comparison). In a method I receive a `list` of Object and I would like to **merge** it with the member one.

The pseudo code of the method is something like:

```
function updateMemberList(list<Object> paramList) {
    for(Object o in paramList){
        if(memberList contains o)
            Replace o in memberList
        else
            Put o in memeberList
    }
}
```

I searched STL documentation for a (or a combination of) method that let me not to write this function, but I haven't found anything: the merge algorithm seems to use a comparator just for ordering. Am I missed the function I need? Is there a better approach to solve the problem?

PS: unfortunately, I can't use C++11 or newer.

Comment: Are the lists sorted by ID?

Comment: You need to give more context of what your C++ code is.... For example is `memberList` a sorted `std::vector`? or a `std::set`? .... How do you replace? By copy assignment?

Comment: not yet but I suppose I could sort them easily

Comment: Why can't you use C++11 or newer exactly? And do provide a [mcve] of your `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps (not tested):

```
typedef std::map<ID_type, std::list<Object>::iterator> IdIterMap;
IdIterMap existing_ids;
for (std::list<Object>::iterator it = memberList.begin();
     it != memberList.end(); ++it) {
  existing_ids[it->ID()] = it;
}
for (std::list<Object>::iterator it = paramList.begin();
     it != paramList.end(); ++it) {
  IdIterMap::iterator map_it = existing_ids.find(it->ID());
  if (map_it != existing_ids.end()) {
    *(map_it->second) = *it;
  } else {
    memberList.push_back(*it);
  }
}
```